# How am I supposed to register a package to PyPI?

Tags: python, pypi

In the documentation for [packaging and distributing Python packages](https://packaging.python.org/distributing/), it says to use `twine` with `repository = https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/` in `.pypirc`. Now this URL is both – from the last bit of it – a legacy way to do things, and a non-existing one at that:

```
$ twine register dist/scriptdoctest-0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
Registering package to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Enter your username: MyUserName
Enter your password: 
Registering scriptdoctest-0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
HTTPError: 410 Client Error: This API is no longer supported, instead simply upload the file. for url: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
```

Is using `scriptdoctest.egg-info/PKG-INFO` now the preferred and only way to register a package, or is there some other way to do this with `twine` or some other CLI tool?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I didn't know Python starting officially recommending Twine for this. Twine is new (not legacy). see https://github.com/pypa/twine#why-should-i-use-this for the benefits of Twine. If you are okay with not gaining those benefits (or you have a very recent version of Python), then feel free to use `python setup.py upload`, which has been the conventional method for many years.

Comment: `python setup.py upload` (or did I try `register` only?) did also give me a `HTTP 410: This API is no longer supported`. Do I just want to not have a `.pypirc` at all?

Comment: Ah, I just reread your OP. I missed the "legacy" in the PyPI URL. If you are not using Twine, then yes, just remove the `.pypirc` file. I've never used one myself. As I understand it (sorry no reference), they are currently in the process of updated PyPI. I'm guessing you are reading prospective documentation which isn't actually effective yet.

Comment: @Anaphory I uploaded a package today and perhaps you may find some info useful.
my `.pypirc` has `repository=https://pypi.python.org/pypi` instead of `repository=https://pypi.python.org/legacyi`. I was not using `twine` and while I register my package with `python setup.py register -r pypi`, I got the same  `Server response (410): This API is no longer supported, instead simply upload the file.` response. And I skipped over to use `python setup.py sdist upload -r pypi` directly. I am purely guessing here, can you try using `twine upload dist/*` directly after changing `.pypirc`?

Comment: I guess you solved it by now? Do you want to write an answer?

Comment: @MartinThoma I actually didn't get round to it among doing so much other stuff.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

https://packaging.python.org/distributing/ actually provides all necessary information.

### TL;DR

1. Create a valid project, especially `setup.py`
2. `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`
3. Make sure you have a correct `~/.pypirc` with your credentials from https://pypi.python.org/pypi
4. `twine upload dist/*` - **it is no longer necessary/possible to register**

My `.pypirc` looks as follows:

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
  pypi
  pypitest

[pypi]
repository=https://pypi.python.org/pypi
username=Martin.Thoma
password=[your password]

[pypitest]
repository=https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
username=Martin.Thoma
password=[your password]
```

Answer (score 5):

Following Martin Thoma answer seem to be deprecated now ([here](https://packaging.python.org/guides/migrating-to-pypi-org/#uploading)).

> It's recommended to use the new URL "https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/"
>   or to leave the URL unspecified and allow twine to choose.

So your `.pypirc` should looks as follow:

```
[pypi]
username=[your username]
password=[your password]

[pypitest]
username=[your username]
password=[your password]
```

Next follow those steps:

1. Create a valid `setup.py` for your project.
2. Create wheel and dist:

   ```
   python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
   ```
3. To avoid having to re-enter your password you can populate `~/.pypirc` with your credentials from
   [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi).
4. Now the upload command takes care of registering, so the command is now:

   ```
   twine upload dist/*
   ```

Comment: This only worked for me if I pointed the twine command at my pypirc file: `twine upload --config-file=.pypirc dist/*`

Comment: Where is your pypirc located ?

Comment: Ah! Should it be at `~/.pypirc`...? I had it in the same directory as this project's `setup.py`.

Comment: You can change it but yes this is the default location.

Comment: @Akelian, I believe we can only omit the url for the real PyPI, but we still have to specify the url for the test PyPI, otherwise how could the tool know which url to use?

Answer (score 3):

Use this repository URL, and it will work `repository = https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/`.

I guess documentation is a bit out of date since a lot has been happening with packaging including the move to warehouse: https://pypi.org/